# Downloading multiple images to display on UI

Tags: ios, swift, caching

Im designing iOS app in swift which downloads 6 images on each screen and I have eight such screens. I'm downloading images asynchronously each time when screen shown. How can I display all images at a time after downloading ..should I use dispatch groups

Also Should I cache my images as there is feasibility for user to go back to previous screen?
if i cache I might have to cache all images (8 screens - 6 Images each : 42 images in total)..isn't it bad practice to have all images in cache?

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea to display all images at a time. Using `DispatchSemaphore`, according to [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore)

> A dispatch semaphore is an efficient implementation of a traditional
>   counting semaphore. Dispatch semaphores call down to the kernel only
>   when the calling thread needs to be blocked. If the calling semaphore
>   does not need to block, no kernel call is made.
>
> You increment a semaphore count by calling the signal() method, and
>   decrement a semaphore count by calling wait() or one of its variants
>   that specifies a timeout.

```
// Declaration
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
...
// resource request
semaphore.wait()
...
// resource release
semaphore.signal()
```

Example

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
   print("download 1 - wait")
   semaphore.wait()
   print("download 1 - wait finished")
   semaphore.signal()
   print("download 1 - finished")
}
```

To cache image or not is depending on your scenario, `NSCache` can do the job if the screen is very important and frequently return to this screen.